# Settimeout: show a div after 5 seconds and then hide it after 10

Tags: settimeout

Probably it will be very easy for you, but i cannot do this.
I need to show a div after 5 seconds and, after showned, wait 5 seconds and hide it. How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
setTimeout(function () {
    document.getElementById('samplediv').style.display='none';
    setTimeout(function () {
        document.getElementById('samplediv').style.display='block';
    }, 5000);
}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="myDiv" hidden>Your Div</div>
</body>
  <script>
    var myDiv = document.getElementById("myDiv");
    setTimeout(function(){
      myDiv.style.display="block";
      console.log("Showing");
      setTimeout(function(){
        console.log("Hiding");
        myDiv.style.display="none";
      },10000);
    },5000);
  </script>
</html>
```